# Simulating mouse and keyboard input on Wayland and X11

Tags: linux, wayland

I am working on a small acceptance test for my OpenGL application written in C. So far, I'm only able to take screenshots and haven't found a way of simulating mouse and keyboard input on both Wayland and X11.

Any suggestions on how to manipulate the event stream of a specific window in Wayland/X11?

Answer (score 8):

For simulating `X11` mouse events you have several options:

1. If your `X server` supports `XTEST` extension (usually it does), then use `XTEST Extension Library` with functions `XTestFakeKeyEvent`,`XTestFakeMotionEvent`, etc. An [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14428438/is-there-any-general-interfaces-on-linux-to-simulate-mouse-movements-and-click)
2. You can use `XLib` functions like `XSendEvent`, `XWarpPointer`, etc. An [example](https://gist.github.com/pioz/726474)
3. If you are under `Linux` and your tests have access to command shell then you can use command line tool `xdotool` (which internally uses `XTEST extension`. An [example](http://xmodulo.com/simulate-key-press-mouse-movement-linux.html)

For `Wayland` you can use `uinput` kernel module. Documentation and examples are [`here`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.12/input/uinput.html)

Comment: Is there anything similar for Wayland?

Comment: BTW, the link of your first example is broken.

Comment: For `Wayland` you can use `uinput` kernel module: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.12/input/uinput.html. And I've checked the link in my first example - it works

Comment: Is your first link supposed to be [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51406276/simulating-mouse-and-keyboard-input-on-wayland-and-x11 ?

Comment: @vinnylinux, you are right, sorry, I didn't meant linking to the current post. Fixed the link

Comment: Unfortunately, that example doesn't work. Not even with XTestFakeKeyEvent. :(

Answer (score 1):

[keyboard](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard) is a Python library designed to emulate keyboard and mouse on both Linux (X11 only) and Windows. There may be a similar project that uses C, but I don't know of it yet.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that [Atbswp](https://github.com/RMPR/atbswp) could be used, but to run it on Wayland I had to add `GDK_BACKEND=x11` while launching it: `GDK_BACKEND=x11 ./atbswpv0.3.0-linux`.

As far as I understand under-the-hood it uses "pyautogui" Python library and make it quite easy to manually modify a script (as it basically seem to generate a Python script file).

That being stated I assume just using "pyautogui" library could be an answer to the original question and atbswp could be used as a helper to generate an appropriate script.

I got to know Atbswp by reading this article: https://www.linuxuprising.com/2020/03/how-to-record-and-play-mouse-and.html, there is some more information about it.